# Request for networkidle-n where navigation to be finished when there are no more than 'n' network connections for at least 500 ms

Tags: puppeteer

Love the tool, but requesting some assistance or for a new feature.
I have pages where I need 3 or less requests open. Having said that `networkidle2` is not sufficient enough for me. I'm aware of using `await page.waitForTimeout(sometime);`, but I'm finding that not good enough for my needs.

Would it be possible to have an `networkidle-n` option to pass into `page.goto()`? Where

> networkidle-n : consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than n network connections for at least 500 ms. Max is set at 6 or even 3.

Or is there something like this already that I'm missing?

Comment: You should be able to implement this yourself with `waitForFunction` or even `evaluate`, and you can check the source code to see how `networkidle2` works, but I'd open a feature request on their GH page if this is what this is.

Comment: Would you happen to know where the source code for `networkidle2` is? I combed most of the puppeteer git and the most I can get is that they are events defined in the puppeteer protocol [link](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/LifecycleWatcher.ts#L32). Would the source code be in the dev-protocol?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't appear obvious -- there's [`networkManager.numRequestsInProgress() === 0`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/2b45027d256f85f21a0c824183696b237e00ad33/src/common/Page.ts#L1970) but I don't see how idle2 would fit into it at a glance. I wonder if you can attach `page.on("request"...` and `page.on("response"...` handlers before the nav, then on request count upward and on response count downward until you reach the desired `n`? With `waitForFunction`/`evaluate`, there's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests